# Transactional Spring Junit4 test cases for Validation scenario

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa, junit4

I am using Spring,JPA using hibernate for service -> dao layer.
Transactions are spring managed.
I have validation testcase wherein , I need to validate for duplicate data insertion and throw an exception.

In my testcase ,which is extension to [AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.html)

I have configured @TransactionConfiguration with defaultRollback as true and bean name for transaction manager (in my case its a bean of JpaTransactionManager)

I execute this testcase as below steps

1. Create a record with call to dao.create(entity); (this will succeed)
2. Create a same record (with all the attributes same as set in step 1) and call dao.create(entity) (this must fail, but its not failing)
3. In my create(entity) method I make call to validate() method, which fires scalar object query (JPQL) to validate.

I expect validation to be failed, but this works without exception and duplicate data gets inserted in DB.

I tried debugging (enabled hibernate logs),I found that the select query (scalar query) fails to get the proper data (ideally it should fetch at least 1 record, as I inserted data for it in step 1 listed above.)

I see Insert query for step1 in logs ,before select query for validation.

Is there any other way to write test case for such scenario which involves spring / jpa with hibernate?

Please post your views

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste your test here, I believe each test is running in its own transaction, and you have defaultRollback as true. That should be the issue.